# How to focus first invalid ngx-formly field

Tags: angular-formly, dynamic-forms, dynamicform, ngx-formly

I am using ngx-formly for creating dynamic form from field configuration. On submitting form, validation is showed correctly. I want to focus first invalid formly field.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party here but I was able to implement a solution that returned the user to the first instance of an invalid input using getElementById:

```
  var errorField = null;
  fields.forEach(field => {
    for (var key in field.formControl["controls"]) {
      let control = field.formControl["controls"][key];
      if (control instanceof FormControl && control.status === "INVALID") {
        errorField = control["_fields"][0]["_elementRefs"][0].nativeElement.id;
        break;
      }
      else if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
        for (var subKey in control.controls) {
          let subControl = control.controls[subKey];
          if (subControl.status === "INVALID") {
            errorField = subControl["_fields"][0]["_elementRefs"][0].nativeElement.id;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      if (errorField) break;
    }
  });

  let el = document.getElementById(errorField);
  el.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
    block: "center"
  });
```